# why <Redirect to='/vacations' /> Does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make simple app with login form on the home page, which redirects then to vacations page. I faced a problem when trying to make `/vacations` page private. Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from "react-router";
import axios from "axios"

class Nav extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        userName: '',
        password: '',
    }
    this.userLogin = this.userLogin.bind(this);
}

  userLogin() {
    let userToChack = {
        userName: this.state.userName,
        password: this.state.password,
    }
    axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/api/login`, userToChack)
        .then(res => {
            if (res.data !== "") {
                // if user name and password OK
                document.getElementById(`helloUser`).innerText = `Hello ${this.state.userName}`;
                document.getElementById(`login`).innerText = `Logout`;
                return <Redirect to='/vacations' />
            } else {
                // if user name or password NOT OK 
                console.log("user can't login");
                document.getElementById(`helloUser`).innerText = ``;
                document.getElementById(`login`).innerText =`Login`;
                return <Redirect to='/' />
            }
        })
}
}
```

Comment: We all need it to work at some point during the year... :p

Comment: Where exactly is the problem and what have you tried so far to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't return `Redirect` outside `render`. If you want to redirect after some imperative code you should use `history.push()`

```
apiCheck = () =>{
    fetchResource().then(res => this.props.history.push('/path'))
}
```

`history` object it's available when wrapping any component (that already is under `Router`) with `withRouter` HOC from `react-router-dom`

```
export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you're actually rendering the component. You have to call `userLogin()` in your render method.